# Auto Login After Registration On WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have WP 4.9.8 website with Ultimate Member plugin (Also Gravity Forms with User Registration and Auto Login addon). Can't figure out how to automatically redirect visitor after registration and automated login to the page he wanted to access (before he was redirected to sign-up form)?. I was looking for a plugin/extension for this, but couldn't find any working properly. My goal is to achieve this with plugin/extension (as for the Gravity Forms, there is such plugin) in the first place, unless there such option does not exist, then use php code to achieve this. Please share Your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

if you are going with Gravity Form plus User Registration Add-on, I used this snippet in past and worked like a charm:

```
add_action('gform_user_registered', 'gf_login_after_registration', 10, 4);
function gf_login_after_registration($user_id, $config, $entry, $password) {
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, false, '');
}
```

You should paste it in your theme's functions.php file.

Alternatively, this is another solution that should work, but I never tested: https://gist.github.com/danielmcclure/f347cfabd02e5e628a0c

Hope this helps!